# rendering a new line in a string (\n) with drawRect

Tags: ios, xcode, newline, line-breaks

I am trying to render a string with a new line (line break \n), using drawRect.

The code below renders the my string as a single line, with no line break, even though I am using the \n character. See the second to last line.

```
UIFont *font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:fontSize];
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0,0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[@"test \n test" drawAtPoint:point withFont:font];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the

```
- (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

method to draw your string.